# Assigning each Control in a TableLayoutPanel to a 2D Array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, foreach, controls, tablelayoutpanel

I created a `TableLayoutPanel` with 100 slots (10x10). In each cell, I created a new `TableLayoutPanel`.
Then I created an array `TableLayoutPanel[,] tb = new TableLayoutPanel[10,10];`

So now I want to loop through each cell of the main (10x10) TableLayoutPanel and assign each `tablelayoutpanel` in each cell to a memory slot in the 2D array.

I have been brainstorming and searching online and kind of got the hint that this is going to involve two `for` loops and one `foreach` loop, but I am confused as to what goes where.

From what I have coded, I think the best place to do the assignment is within this block of code:

```
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                    {
                        mainTPL.Controls.Add(new TableLayoutPanel
                        {
                            Name = "tbl" + i + "-" + j,
                            CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Inset,
                            Size = new Size(70, 70),
                            RowCount = 2,
                            ColumnCount = 3,
                        }, i, j);
                      //Could I do the assignment right here?
                    }
                }
```

I don't have a for each loop, but is is possible to do the assignment in that double loop? How could I specify the newly created `TableLayoutPanel` to assign it in the array?
Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way to do it using nested `if` statements. I bet there's other ways to do it, but this works for me for now. Hope this helps someone.

```
TableLayoutPanel[,] grid = new TableLayoutPanel[10, 10];
    int k=0,l=0;   
     foreach (TableLayoutPanel c in mainTPL.Controls)
                        {  
                            if(k<10 && l<10)
                            {
                                 grid[k, l] = c;
                                 if (l != 9)
                                     l++;
                                 else
                                 {
                                        l = 0;
                                        k++;
                                 }
                            }
                        }
```